# Get different permissions when logged in locally vs being logged in remotely

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have a weird thing happening on two of my sql servers. I am using a domain user account that has admins rights to both of the sql servers. When I log onto sql server_1 locally and connect to local sql instance via Microsoft Sql management studio , I don't see all of my stored procedures and views. The ones I see are encrypted. But if I connect to sql server_2 via MS studio remotely from server_1 I get full permissions to sql server_2. Then, If i do it the other way around: I log onto sql server_2, I get the whole permission thing reversed. I can connect to sql server_1 remotely and get full permissions but when I connect to local instance (sql server_2) I get encrypted stored procedures and views.

I use the same account in both cases. Please help.

Comment: Local admin rights are different than SSMS rights.  Are you logging into SSMS with Windows authentication when you are on the server, and with SSMS identification when you are remote?

Comment: I used windows authentication on both of the server. Also, on both of the server my windows account is a member of local administrator group that is , in turn, a member of sql admin group.(I have a builtin/adminstrators group on both of sql servers)

Comment: I would try logging in with SSMS auth instead (from the server), just to rule that out.  It definitely sounds like a break in admin privileges somewhere.  That said, if SPs remain encrypted, you might check out the answers in this question http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60129/how-to-view-an-encrypted-view-or-stored-procedure

Comment: I realize that question is about how to decrypt, not why they are encrypted, but some of the answers seem to hit more on your point.  If nothing else it's an interesting read and perhaps someone will visit this question who has had your exact issue in the meantime.

Comment: Not really, the question is about why I don't get admin permissions when I use SSMS locally but when I do it from a different host with the same account, I get admin rights to everything.

Comment: What version of sql server are you using?